# Vis.js - Accessing data by clicking on a 3D bar

Tags: angular, vis.js

I'm working with **vis.js** to visualize data in a 3D graph, but I'm encountering problems with the `onclick` option, which can be set on a `vis.Graph3d` graph.
How can I extract the data of the point that I'm clicking on?
For example save that data in a predefined variable or pass it to a service... I have no problem logging the data in the console, but can't seem to pass it into a variable.

PS: Using vis.js in my **Angular5** project.

What I'm trying to do:

```
export class Vis3dGraphDirective {
        public selectedData;
        public DEFAULT_OPTIONS = {
           onclick: function onclick (point) {
             console.log(point.syle + ', ' + point.z + ', ' + point.x + ', ' + 
             point.y); //works fine
             this.selectedData.z = point.z; //does not work
             this.vdService.setSelectedData(point.z); //does not work
           },
           ...
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use arrow function to retain `this`

```
onclick: (point) => {
```

Read also

- https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/%27this%27-in-TypeScript

Comment: Thanks a lot! I should've known this and feel embarrassed. Works just fine of course.

Comment: You're welcome! Consider accepting the answer if it helped.